# How do u replace a string that's not inside a specific div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I have this html:

```
<div id="content">This following word is not <span id="notOk">ok</span> but all the other words are ok</div>
```

And using this jquery I'm trying to replace the word `ok` with `cool`, as long as the word `ok` is not inside the span `#notOk`.

```
var content = $('#content').html()
content = content.replace('ok', 'cool');
$('#content').html(content)
```

I also want to preserve the sentence and not move any words around, which is what happened when I tried.  I guess I'm looking for something like dontGetElementByID('').?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/p8a7V/1/)

Comment: Not getting what you wanted to say.

Comment: You mean to say that you want the word 'ok' gets replaced with 'cool' if its in span with Id=#notOk? And other 'ok' should not get replaced. Am I right?

Comment: What do you want do?? change the first ok inside the span, the ok outside the span, or both?

Comment: After the replace I want the html to be `This following word is not <span id="notOk">ok</span> but all the other words are cool</div>` instead of `This following word is not <span id="notOk">cool</span> but all the other words are ok</div>` which is what is happening.. Is that clearer?

Comment: @user2891084 change the `ok` outside the span

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `.contents()` method and replace `nodeValue` properties of the `textNode`s.

```
$('#content').contents().each(function(){
    if (this.nodeType === 3)
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace('ok', 'cool');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/82tmP/

Comment: Very cool.  And will this work if the #notOk span wraps different words and the replace method is called on those?  It seems to.  THanks : )

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p8a7V/3/ Awesome http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodetype.asp Cool stuff

Answer (score 3):

Replace the value just like you did.. then replace it back :)

```
var content = $('#content').html()
content = content.replace('ok', 'cool');
$('#content').html(content);

content = $('#notOk').html();
content = content.replace('cool', 'ok');
$('#notOk').html(content);
```